# Hive ODBC connection with dbplyr Invalid table alias or column reference

Tags: r, odbc, dbplyr

I'm connected to Hive using dbplyr and odbc.

A table I would like to connect to is called "pros_year_month":

```
library(odbc)
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "HiveProd")
prosym <- tbl(con, in_schema("my_schema_name", "pros_year_month"))
```

Table pros_year_month has several fields, two of which are "country" and "year_month".

This appears to work without any problem:

```
pros_nov <- prosym %>% filter(country == "United States") %>% collect()
```

However this does not:

```
pros_nov <- prosym %>% filter(year_month = ymd(as.character(paste0(year_month, "01")))) %>% collect()
```

> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) :
>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42000: [Hortonworks][Hardy] (80) Syntax or
>   semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error
>   message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
>   SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:7 Invalid table alias or
>   column reference 'zzz1.year_month': (possible column names are:
>   year_month, country, ...

It looks like the field name year_month is somehow now zzz1.year_month? Not sure what this is or how to get around it.

How can I apply a filter for country then year_month before calling collect on a dbplyr object?

Comment: Hi Doug Fir, I am having similar issue when querying Hive from R. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Hi Nitish. I'm not at the same company so don't have access to that particular server with Hosted RStudio however I remember that I never found a solution and in the end just used raw SQL text as opposed to `prosym <- tbl(con, in_schema("my_schema_name", "pros_year_month"))`
By the way it works for me here at new company and I suspect it was to do with an older version of Java that my old place used for their Hive tables

Comment: Cool, will try to get Java updated and see if it works. Thanks for the help.